# How can I test out a line graph I made in Excel 2016 in an older version of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

Currently I was making some graphs and manipulating some data. It looks pretty good so far. Problem is : I left my work computer at work, and need to have some graphs tommorow. The work computers generally all have Excel 2007.

I was having some problems earlier today making the graph on my work computer and got home and dabbled around and finally got my desired graph. Now I'm not sure whether or not this is because Excel 2016 optimizes some things better, or I just formatted my data much better. Is there a way I can "test" how my graph and data would look if I opened it in Excel 2007, without actually having it?

**I dont see .xls**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save your workbook in `.xls` format instead of `.xlsx` format. You should have no problems with the graph. Excel 2007 should be able to read everything and display it in the way you see on excel 2016.

If you used any featured not available in older versions of excel, while saving, you will be presented with a dialog box telling you what features will be discarded when you save as `.xls`.

[Save an Excel 2016 workbook for compatibility with earlier versions of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Excel-2016-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-169a0336-965b-4430-8554-4e7b5db79947)

Additionally, you can always install excell 2007 along-side excell 2016.

Comment: Suppose I used a feature not available in Excel 2007 ( Which I probably have, honestly the graph portion here looks alot different, but I'm not sure if its just the layout looking alot more fancy so its just my eyes). When I open it at work, will those features disseapear? I don't want half my graph to be gone when I open it tomorrow.

Comment: "Suppose I used a feature not available in Excel 2007" -- When you save, as `.xls` excel will tell you if you were using a newer feature. This is because `.xls` files are Excel 2003 compatible.  At this point, you review your graph and remove the offending feature.

Comment: Additionally, you can always install excell 2007 along-side excell 2016. (updated in my answer above.)

Comment: I added a picture above, I dont see any .xls

Comment: Chose `Excel 97-2003 Workbook` -  thats the third option.

Comment: It tells me how some of my line colors might be a bit different, nothing else. I guess I should be ok..?

Comment: yes, Excel 2016 supports more colors than excel 97 (for example) since you wont go that back for compatibility, you should be okay. Normally Excel 2007 would display all of these colors.